# PHP Sessions and mobile devices

Tags: php, ios, session, windows-phone-8, authentication

I'm having some problems with PHP sessions and mobile devices, in this case an iPad (1st gen) and an Nokia Lumia 720. I have some test site (`http://localhost:8888/php-test/`) with this code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    echo '$_SESSION["language"] was set to: ' . $_SESSION['language'];
} else {
    echo '$_SESSION["language"] was NOT set.';
}

$_SESSION['language'] = 'en';
```

In the PC (macbook) everything works fine, but when I try to access to this test site from any of the devices (using `http://192.168.0.30:8888/php-test/` it does not work!

The first time I enter the site, the else part runs. If I refresh the page, the if part runs. But when I close the browser and enter again, the else part appears again..

Any help will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal behaviour as the session cookie is removed when the browser is closed.

Comment: but in the pc I can close the browser and when I re-open it, the session is still there (I mean, the page shows the if part of the code)

Comment: That should not happen. Make sure you are refreshing the tab when you opening it again as it might be cached.

Comment: maybe I explained myself bad. when I say "close the browser" I mean "close the tab". If I close the tab, and then open another tab, the session should still persist (AFAIK)